# python in vscode - standard output results pane

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, output

the terminal is showing (mostly) errors and (sometimes) results.
Is there a way to have another live pane within vscode, showing only the output results (like print(), display() etc.)?
Cause now I need scroll tons to find results from previous runs..

tried send output to a txt then getting it in a second terminal - but they were not updated live.

Comment: If you're seeing errors in the terminal then you should resolve them, but the best way to "silence" pythonic errors is to `catch` them in a try/catch block and simply ignore them. VSCode is not part of the equation here, it just displays whatever your program puts in the terminal (including errors).

Comment: It doesn't look as if there is any such functionality, perhaps additional plugins need to be found. I've filed a report in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22785). Also there are [*Run Python File in Dedicated Terminal*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-june-2023-release/#run-python-file-in-dedicated-terminal) features you might be interested in.